# Connecting and Updating to Database through VB.NET "Select command property has not been ... "

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I am using [this guide](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/821765/how-to-use-microsoft-visual-basic-net-to-connect-to-a-microsoft-access) to update a value in a database through VB.NET and really struggling to get it to work.

I am trying to add 1 to a particular cell in the database. The grid that I am using updates with the value, but the database itself doesn't change. Using different tutorials (and loads of other StackOverflow questions) I have changed the code from the original but nothing seems to work.

Each time I click the button that should trigger the addition, I get [this error message.](https://imgur.com/a/BgrPI)

"The select command property has not been initialized before calling fill"

If anyone could tell me what is going wrong or point me in the direction that I should go in, it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Dim senderGrid = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    Dim OleDbDataAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    If TypeOf senderGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewButtonColumn AndAlso
       e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        ' If addition 
        If e.ColumnIndex = 3 Then
            Try
                'from microsoft tut
                ProjectDatabaseDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(e.RowIndex).Item("ProductStock") = ProjectDatabaseDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(e.RowIndex).Item("ProductStock") + 1
                OleDbDataAdapter.Fill(ProjectDatabaseDataSet.Product)
                OleDbDataAdapter.Update(ProjectDatabaseDataSet.Product)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
```

Comment: You are creating a ***new*** DataAdapter in that method, so neither the connection nor the command can be set yet.  The tutorial clearly says to `Drag an OleDbDataAdapter control to Form1.` It does not say to create one in code.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I could not find an OleDbDataAdapter inside the toolbox, so I thought to make one myself. Further googling showed me that I needed to change the toolbox to find one. Thank you for clarifying/ helping :)

Comment: DataSets/DataTables work very closely with the DataAdapter.  In strongly typed ones (which is what you are playing with) there are designer tools to link the 2.  Even with ones you create in code, you usually do not need/want a *local* DataAdapter - you can teach them all they need to know to Add/Insert/Delete and only have one line of SQL in your app.  They do much more than just fill DataTables.  please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: That guide you're using was probably written over a decade ago, before the release of VB 2005. Back in those days, data adapters components were included in the Toolbox by default. That's no longer the case, because it doesn't make sense with typed `DataSets` being available. In your case, you need to use a table adapter rather than a data adapter. The two are similar (a table adapter actually wraps a data adapter) but the table adapter provides more. You can drag a table adapter from the Toolbox just as you would have a data adapter in "the old days".